# Proof Verification of Cayley Hamilton

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I am wondering about how this proof I am doing for the cayley hamilton is and if it is fully valid. I am also interested in any suggestions, better options or things I should note. Or if I am on right track etc,  or were I go wrong?

$\mathbf{Thereom}:$ Every matrix A is a root of its characteristic polynomial

$\mathbf {Proof}:$

Let A $\in \mathbb M_{nxn}$,

and let  $ \nabla(t)=|tI-A|=$$t^{n}+a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+…+a_1t+a_0$$ $ denote the characteristic polynomial of A. ( Which is therefore monic and of degree n) (How can I prove this?).

Let B(t) denote the adjoint of (tI-A), that is, we have $$(tI-A)B(t)=B(t)(tI-A)=|tI-A|I$$

Because B is obtained my crossing out a row and column of A, we have a polynomial with degree of most n-1 (How can I prove this?).

$$B(t)=B_{n-1}t^{n-1}+B_{n-2}t^{n-2}+…+B_1t+B_0$$

so $$(tI-A)B(t)=IB_{n-1}t^{n}-AB_{n-1}t^{n-1}+IB_{n-2}t^{n-1}-AB_{n-2}t^{n-2}+…+B_{1}t^2-AB_{1}t+B_{0}t-AB_{0}$$

If we equate coefficients, we have $$B_{n-1}=I$$ $$(B_{n-2}-AB_{n-1})=a_{n-1}$$… $$B_{0}-AB_{1}=a_1$$ $$-AB_{0}=a_0$$

Multiplying respectively by $A^{n}$ , $A^{n-1}$ … A and adding the sides leaves $0=a_nA^{n}+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}+…+ao$

QED

Comment: This is the proof in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley–Hamilton_theorem#A_direct_algebraic_proof). Did you come up with this proof on your own? If so, well done!

Comment: @Ihf I wish! I did a lot of it but only after getting a hint to use the adjoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of confusing steps, but the general idea is sound. First of all, $B(t)$ is the adjoint of $tI-A$, not $A$. This becomes clear when you write the equation for it, but the initial declaration is wrong.

Second, when you are equating coefficients, you should write out the other side $|tI-A|I$ as $\sum a_kt^kI$, so then the coefficient equality becomes $B_{n-2} - AB_{n-1} = a_{n-1} I$. The way you have it written, one side is a matrix, the other scalar.

**edit** for help with remaining proof steps.
Write out what the elements of $tI - A$ are, expressed in terms of $t$ and the elements of $A$. How many elements with $t$ are there? What will the formula for determinant look like with these elements multiplied? Similarly, each element of $B(t)$ is the determinant of a matrix formed by deleting a row and a column from $tI -A$. How many elements with $t$ in them are left in such a matrix? What does it mean if each element of a matrix is a polynomial in $t$ of a certain degree?